# Delphi Firemonkey Xe 8 TreeView Argument out of range on TreeViewItem.EndUpdate

Tags: delphi, treeview, firemonkey, treeviewitem, delphi-xe8

I have a TreeView on a form and a button that clears the items and adds new items in
If there are enough items to go off the screen so you have to scroll to view them all, the second time i click the button i'm getting "Argument out of range" error
 
If the form is big enough to fit all the items it seems to be happy
If i take out the tv1.BeginUpdate and tv1.EndUpdate it sometimes works but still get the Argument out of range error randomly

```
procedure TfrmMain.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i : Integer;
begin
  tv1.Clear;
  tv1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to 10 do begin
      with TTreeViewItem.Create( tv1 ) do begin
        Parent := tv1;
        Text := inttostr(i);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    tv1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Here is an example project 
https://github.com/dangas56/Delphi-XE8-TreeNode-ArgumentOutOfRange-Error
Remember to click the basic fill button twice

EDIT: If anyone can suggest another component that allows you to expand and collapse sub-items please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I try to investigate and your code seems OK. I think the problem come from FMX.Controls file. I try to edit and modify it, but seems it need more investigation. I advise to declare a bug to embarcadero. (it depend the size of the screen, and the error appear in then EndUpdate command)

Comment: Ive added an issue to QC [https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11502](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11502) .Not holding my breath that ill hear anything back

Comment: Did you try to contact the support ? directly ?

Comment: i wasn't aware you could. would you call them directly? [http://support.embarcadero.com/contact](http://support.embarcadero.com/contact) or some other way?

Comment: i'm using this link : https://login.salesforce.com/sserv/login.jsp?orgId=00DA0000000KPcd

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to put tv1.Clear after the tv1.BeginUpdate (ie as the first line inside the Try... Finally).